# Haskell records with default values using lens without _

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make record with default values and avoid using underscores when making records. I currently am using:

```
data SectionedItems s i = SectionedItems{
    _section :: Maybe s,
    _items :: [i],
    _subsections :: [SectionedItems s i]
}
makeLenses ''SectionedItems

sectionedItems = SectionedItems{
    _section = Nothing,
    _items = [],
    _subsections = []
}

-- Create Instance of SectionedItems
sectionedItems
    & section .~ Just x
```

Is there a shorter or clearer way to make a record with default values and without underscores?

Comment: You probably will want to look at [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a handy package called [data-default](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default) which defines a typeclass `Default` which exposes one function `def :: a` - a default value. Furthermore, although I can't seem to find any documentation for it, you can derive it automatically (with the right flags and things imported). Of course you can always declare the instance yourself if your default has to be different.

Then, you can ease a bit of the pain in your example with something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Default
import GHC.Generics
import Control.Lens

data SectionedItems s i = SectionedItems{
    _section :: Maybe s,
    _items :: [i],
    _subsections :: [SectionedItems s i]
} deriving (Generic,Default)
makeLenses ''SectionedItems

-- Create a SectionedItems - this could have whatever type you want
def & section .~ Just 3 :: SectionedItems Int [String]
```

(Try not to use 'instance' like you would in OOP since Haskell has a very different meaning for instance).

However that doesn't do away with the underscores in `Lens`. I'm not sure what you *could* do for that. The bottom line is that the functions `makeLenses''` generates for you can't have name clashes with the functions Haskell generates for you when you create records. By looking in [Control.Lens.TH](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html) you can see that you can regulate the lens names to be what you want, but bottom line you will have to settle on a convention - the underscore for record accessors and no underscore for lens is as good a convention as any.

### EDIT

If you want to define the default value explicitly, you make an instance of `Default`:

```
instance Default (SectionedItems s i) where
  def = SectionedItems { _section = Nothing, _items = [], _subsections = [] }
```

Comment: Another convention I've used is to name all the record field labels with a prefix for the data type, as in `sectionedItemsSections`. At least some of the options in Control.Lens.TH will strip off the prefix for the generated lens names, and this plays well with using the `makeFields` stuff for lenses that are overloaded for multiple data types (since it also stops the record field labels from clashing, though they're now extremely verbose).

Comment: Don't you need to use `TemplateHaskell` language extension to make Lenses work?

Comment: @klappvisor, to use the convenient `makeLenses`, etc., features, yes. To write lenses by hand and use them, no.

Comment: @2426021684 Let me check that out. I should've tried that instance before typing it in.